# Get previous 4 weeks data based on date excluding current week

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My Table:

```
Id(Varchar2)        Load(varchar2)         Date(TIMESTAMP)      Value(number)
I123                    T123                 15/05/2020            15
I123                    T345                 14/05/2020            13
I123                    T456                 07/05/2020            30
I456                    T657                 15/05/2020            15
I456                    T890                 14/05/2020            13
I678                    T127                 30/04/2020            30
I764                    T163                 15/05/2020            15
I543                    T895                 10/05/2020            13
I111                    T423                 07/05/2020            30
I111                    T154                 27/04/2020            15
I444                    T899                 21/04/2020            13
I432                    T111                 30/04/2020            30
```

What I required is

```
Id  Week-1(strt-end date)  week-2(strt-end date)   week-3(strt-end date)   week-4(strt-end date)  avg
I123         2                        1                      0                        0         19.3333
```

1. Week1-->previous week  Week2--->before previous week.....so on
2. strt and end dates are for that particular week
3. values in week1,2,3,4 are no. of loads in that week for that id
4. avg=sum(value)/count(load) for that particular id

What I tried:

```
select id, (case when week_no=(to_char(sysdate,'IW')-1) then load else 0 end) week0,
(case when week_no=(to_char(sysdate,'IW')-2) then loads else 0 end) week1,
(case when week_no=(to_char(sysdate,'IW')-3) then loads else 0 end) week2,
(case when week_no=(to_char(sysdate,'IW')-4) then loads else 0 end) week3,
avg_ape from
(select id,count(load) loads, to_char(date,'IW') WEEK_NO,sum(value)/count(load) AVG_APE
from data group by to_char(date,'IW'),zip3lane order by id asc
) order by id asc;
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of sub-query. You can achieve the desired result using conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select id,
       COUNT(case when trunc(sysdate - 7,'IW') = trunc(date,'IW') THEN load END) AS week0,
       COUNT(case when trunc(sysdate - 14,'IW') = trunc(date,'IW') THEN load END) AS week1,
       COUNT(case when trunc(sysdate - 21,'IW') = trunc(date,'IW') THEN load END) AS week2,
       COUNT(case when trunc(sysdate - 28,'IW') = trunc(date,'IW') THEN load END) AS week3,
       sum(value)/count(load) as avg_ape
from data group by id;
```